# how to compare two collection in Firebase flutter application?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have store two collection of documents in Firebase. One collection having user details(like..uid,photourl,etc) and another collection having users chats with other users ,but in second collection doesn't have user details(like photourl).
I want to join two collections using (==)comparision in stream builder
I have attached screenshots for reference.
[image: Firebase Collection]

[image: Flutter code]

Comment: do you really want to compare or just want relation between two collection?

Comment: compare two collection and  pass into stream builder

Answer (score 0):

I am not all that sure of what you are trying to do with the `==` in your code (as `DocumentReference`s will be different as they fall in different collections), but if you are looking to join the two streams together, take a look at [RxDart's combineLatest2](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Rx/combineLatest2.html), which allows you to get a new stream with the latest elements of the other two streams.

Also, I am not sure if calling `snapshot.data.documents` is guaranteed to give you the documents in sorted order; thus, calling `[index]` may not do what you want in that case as well.

One thing I would like to note: the way you are structuring your data seems fairly odd--why not just put all the user data under the user collection?